# dart: cannot resolve class name 'ListBase' from 'ListWrapper

Tags: dart, dart-webui

Tried the webui_click tutorial target

Got an error

```
cannot resolve class name 'ListBase' from 'ListWrapper
```

Using this version of Dart Editor

```
Dart Editor version 0.4.5_r21094
Dart SDK version 0.4.5.1_r21094
A new version [21823] is ready to install
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Dart Editor to latest version under Help/About Dart Editor and problem went away

```
Dart Editor version 0.5.0_r21823
Dart SDK version 0.5.0.1_r21823
```

Comment: Earlier, I tried to update Dart Editor and when it came back up when I tried to create a new application it would not create the packages folder and I rolled back to the earlier version of the editor and the problem went away. Then I updated the Dart Editor for a this webui_click_counter tutorial and the earlier misbehavior of not creating the packages folder did not re-occur.

Comment: Next problem I ran into was that it gave an error about not finding import 'package:web_ui/component_build.dart';
So I commented it out and saved and uncommented it and the problem went away.